# knockout.js and .htaccess in ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ubuntu, knockout.js

HTML file

```
<div id="demo">
  <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
  <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
  <button data-bind="click: myFunctionSave">Save</button>
  <button data-bind="click: myFunctionCancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ViewModel/knockout-2.3.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ViewModel/main.js'></script>
```

JavaScript file

```
function myFunctionSave() {
   this.firstName = "save";this.lastName = "saveSurname";
 }
 function myFunctionCancel() {
   this.firstName = "cancel";this.lastName = "cancelSurname";
 }
  ko.applyBindings(new myFunctionSave());
  ko.applyBindings(new myFunctionCancel());
```

.htaccess

I'm unable to create a .htaccess in ubuntu 12.04 lts. I have unhided it and even done all in Apache from none but still it is redirecting to the localhost home page and says "YES ITS WORKING"
but not redirected to index.html.

tried this code it is working
html file

```
<div class='demo'> 
 <button data-bind='click: save'>save</button>
 <button data-bind='click: cancel'>cancel</button>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ViewModel/knockout-2.3.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ViewModel/main.js'></script>
```

javascript file

```
 var student = function() {
   var self = this;
   self.save = function() { alert("save" );  };
    self.cancel = function() { alert("cancel" );  };
 };
 ko.applyBindings(new student());
```

but why this code is not working
html file

```
  <div class='demo'> 
 <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
 <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
 <button data-bind='click: save'>save</button>
 <button data-bind='click: cancel'>cancel</button>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='ViewModel/knockout-2.3.0.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='ViewModel/main.js'></script>
```

javscript file

```
var student = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.save = function() { alert("save" ); 
         self.firstName="save";      
         self.lastName="saveLastname";  };
    self.cancel = function() { alert("cancel" );
         self.firstName="cancel";
         self.lastName="cancelLastname"; };
   };
```

ko.applyBindings(new student());

please help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache (it isn't enabled out of the box).

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# sudo a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
i have this sir but i think it is already been enable and the problem still resists